# What is the meaning of "partisan estrangement of impeachment"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I took the expression from [this](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/06/01/politics/trump-white-house-racial-unrest-leadership/index.html) paragraph:

> But earlier this year -- even amid the **partisan estrangement of impeachment** -- no one could have foreseen how his reelection race will now be shaped by a nation that is battling deep health, economic and social crises at the same time.

I suppose **partisans** are Trump supporters here.

All occurrences of **"estrangement of [noun]"** I found on the web are often followed by **"and/from [noun]"**:

- The increasing estrangement of German and Anglo-Saxon feeling
- ESTRANGEMENT OF GREAT BRITAIN AND JAPAN
- I agree estrangement of adult children from their parents [...]

Thats why **estrangement of impeachment** (without complement) sounds odd to me.

Maybe **partisan estrangement of impeachment** means "Trump supporters disagreeing with (or rejecting) the idea of impeachment"?

Thanks!

Comment: Read "of" as meaning "caused by".

Comment: Thanks @HotLicks. So, putting in other words, "the estrangement of Trump and his partisans due to an imminent impeachment"?

Comment: Not quite.  "Estrangement" occurs *between* different people or groups.  "Partisan estrangement" means "estrangement due partisan divisions".

Comment: You mean estrangement happened between partisan groups themselves (due to disagreeing regarding impeachment maybe) instead of between Trump and the partisan base as a whole?

Comment: "Partisan base" is meaningless unless you specify which side it refers to.

Comment: Yeah, I meant "**his** partisan base", the "fragmentation of **his** partisan base".

Comment: Well, I’d read it this way: there are partisans. Two groups. The process of impeachment estranges them, i.e., the two groups are set against each other, one group *taking the part of* Trump and the other group opposing him (trying to impeach him).

Comment: Yeah, basically the estrangement is claimed to be occurring between the Republicans and the Democrats, making it even harder for them to negotiate or work together.

Comment: I read this as meaning that the act of impeachment by one party (a "partisan" act) has deeply divided ("estranged") the two parties. The word "partisan" is *not* limited to Trump supporters--it applies to both sides, which are now estranged due to the impeachment process.

Comment: You are right that every use of the word word *estrangement* needs to make it clear what is estranged from what, and that this sentence fails to do that. The conventions of this site, however, discourage answers that simply say to the OP 'yes you are right', so it is unlikely that anybody will post that as an answer. One can offer a reasonable interpretation of the sentence, but in doing so one is using one's independent knowledge of the events to guess what was on the author's mind, rather than analysing the sentence as it stands.